# MS Access SQL: in a query check if a field contains spaces and if it's equal to another field without them

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, spaces

Is it possible to check if a table field contains spaces (one or multiple spaces) by using an MS-Access query? (if yes, how?)

I would to know if the A1 field of Table1 contains spaces and check if it without spaces is equal to field B1 of Table2 (without changing the tables data).

I've MS-Access 2007.

**EDIT**

Correct answer for MS-Access 2007:

```
SELECT DISTINCT your_table1.id FROM your_table1, your_table2 
WHERE A1 LIKE '* *' 
AND REPLACE(A1,' ','') IN (SELECT B1 FROM your_table2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Replace in where clause to check spaceless version of A1

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE A1 LIKE '% %' 
AND REPLACE(A1,' ','') IN (SELECT B1 FROM Table 2)
```

Comment: Are you sure they are spaces then? It could be another weird character displayed like a space.

Comment: The issue was in the LIKE, on MS-Access the * must be used instead of %. So the LIKE works, but not the REPLACE(A1,' ','') IN (SELECT B1 FROM Table 2). I think I have to add Table2 in the FROM.

Comment: It works in my tables, just tested. Can you share an sql fiddle?

Comment: There is no SQLFiddle for VBA or JET Support. Only Postgres, MySQL, Oracle 11g, SQL Server 2008, 2012